# Unique values of columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

My table looks like below and I Need to get the unique values of colA and colb with first value of colC

```
ID    ColA   ColB   ColC
1      A1     B1    c1
2      A1     B1    c2
3      A2     B2    c3
4      A2     B2    c4
```

EXPECTED RESULT

```
A1  B1   C1
A2  B2   c3
```

Any help on this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use `MIN()` which is an aggregate function and group the records by `ColA and ColB`

```
SELECT  ColA, ColB, MIN(ColC) ColC
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY ColA, ColB
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/afdf3/1)

**UPDATE 1**

```
WITH records
AS
(
    SELECT  ID, ColA, ColB, ColC,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ColA, ColB ORDER BY ID) rn
    FROM    TableName
)
SELECT  ColA, ColB, ColC
FROM    records
WHERE   rn = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/afdf3/2)

Comment: Thanks. But MIN() will give the minimum value of that group . How do I get the first value.